# Is it possible to run multiple Slurm job-steps which us a single GPU?

Tags: parallel-processing, jobs, slurm, job-scheduling

I have been trying to use Slurm to run multiple job steps on a single GPU. I know memory won't be an issue if the jobs were able to run, however only the first job step will run in the below sequence.

I have seen multiple places where the issues of assigning different jobs to the same GPU was addressed but not individual job-steps within the same job.

I have tried the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --qos bham
#SBATCH -t 0-4:0:0
#SBATCH --ntasks=3
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --gres gpu:1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=10G

module purge
module load baskerville

srun --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK --exclusive bash -c "nvidia-smi ; sleep 60" &
srun --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK --exclusive bash -c "nvidia-smi ; sleep 60" &
srun --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK --exclusive bash -c "nvidia-smi ; sleep 60" &

wait
```

and only a single job-step launched (517334.0):

```
sacct --jobs 517334 --format jobid,ntasks,elapsed,state,alloctres%35,NCPUS,maxrss


       JobID   NTasks    Elapsed      State                           AllocTRES      NCPUS     MaxRSS 
------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------------------------------- ---------- ---------- 
517334                  00:00:42    RUNNING billing=4,cpu=4,gres/gpu=1,mem=40G+          4            
517334.batch        1   00:00:42    RUNNING     cpu=4,gres/gpu=1,mem=40G,node=1          4            
517334.exte+        1   00:00:42    RUNNING billing=4,cpu=4,gres/gpu=1,mem=40G+          4            
517334.0            1   00:00:37    RUNNING     cpu=1,gres/gpu=1,mem=10G,node=1          1
```

I was aiming to achieve something similar to what happens below when not requesting a GPU where all 3 job-steps have been run (517343.0, 517343.1, 517343.2):

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --qos bham
#SBATCH -t 0-4:0:0
#SBATCH --ntasks=5
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=10G

module purge
module load baskerville

srun --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK --exclusive bash -c "echo hello; sleep 60" &
srun --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK --exclusive bash -c "echo hello; sleep 60" &
srun --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK --exclusive bash -c "echo hello; sleep 60" &
wait
```

```
sacct --jobs 517343 --format jobid,ntasks,elapsed,state,alloctres%35,NCPUS,maxrss

       JobID   NTasks    Elapsed      State                           AllocTRES      NCPUS     MaxRSS 
------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------------------------------- ---------- ---------- 
517343                  00:00:24    RUNNING      billing=6,cpu=6,mem=60G,node=1          6            
517343.batch        1   00:00:24    RUNNING                cpu=6,mem=60G,node=1          6            
517343.exte+        1   00:00:24    RUNNING      billing=6,cpu=6,mem=60G,node=1          6            
517343.0            1   00:00:19    RUNNING                cpu=1,mem=10G,node=1          1            
517343.1            1   00:00:19    RUNNING                cpu=1,mem=10G,node=1          1            
517343.2            1   00:00:19    RUNNING                cpu=1,mem=10G,node=1          1
```

If it is not possible to launch multiple job-steps on a single GPU what would be the recommended work around?

Answer (score 1):

The GPUs will not be shared among jobs or job steps unless configured explicitly to be so. The latest option is [sharding](https://slurm.schedmd.com/gres.html#Sharding). In that case, you would request 3*`N` shards in the submission script, and `N` shards in the `srun` line.

Another option is to remove the call to `srun` altogether. In your example, as you work on a single node, it should work as expected.

A third option, if you really need/want `srun`, is to use [--multi-prog](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html#OPT_multi-prog) to only have one `srun` call that would run all three instances of  `bash -c '...'`. That would account for one step, having access to the whole GPU, running programs in parallel.